# Animating images in JavaScript vs Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, animation, phonegap

I'm using PhoneGap (JavaScript) to move images (249px*249px) under your finger (until you remove your finger) and also 8 times a second there comes a little image (49px * 49px) out of it that moves for 1 second and then gets removed. It needs to support 9 fingers on the screen. So there can be 81 images on the screen that are moving, I'm calculating it at 30 times a second and all this makes the screen laggy if there are more than 3 fingers.

If I do the same with Android Studio it all runs smoothly.

**Code I use in PhoneGap:**

```
var frames = 30;
function moveSterrenLoop(x, y, smallImage, runs) {
    if (runs < frames) {
        smallImage.style.left = (parseInt(smallImage.style.left) + x) + "px";
        smallImage.style.top = (parseInt(smallImage.style.top) + y) + "px";

        if (runs >= frames/2) {
            smallImage.style.opacity= window.getComputedStyle(smallImage).getPropertyValue("opacity") - (2/frames);
        }
        runs++;
        setTimeout(function () {
                moveSterrenLoop(x, y, smallImage, runs);
            }, 1000/frames);
    } else {
        smallImage.parentNode.removeChild(smallImage);
    }
}
```

- Touch -move,-start, -end + creating small images and calculating x and y value 8x a second

**Code I use in Android Studio:**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
        //calculate xEnd, yEnd,...
        ...
        smallImage.animate()
            .translationX(xEnd)
            .translationY(yEnd)
            .setDuration(1000)
            .start();
    }
};
```

+onTouchEvent

So my question is: Why is it laggy on PhoneGap and not on Android Studio and how can I fix it?

Can it be because in handlers/runnables run in background (on other thread, not the main thread) and PhoneGap does it line after line?

Comment: You can try doing `100/frames` meaning you update it less times and it doesn't lag as much or switching to `.style.transform = "translate("+x+"px, "+y+"px)";` which is GPU accelerated

Comment: thanks for your comment, It's better now in combination with: lowering frame rate, using style.transform (which u both sugested) and using setInterval on a function with a for loop that moves every small image so all the moving happens in 2 loops and not in 81 different loops. If u can put those 3 in an answer I will check it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because of the speed of your timeout and because you are not using a GPU accelerated css style

By using a GPU accelerated CSS style such as `transform`, you can decrease the lag

```
smallImage.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
```

If you do this less often, you can further decrease the lag

```
}, 3000/frames);
```

If by lowering the framerate it appears more laggy, you can use a CSS transition. This may make things appear less responsive

```
transition: 0.1s transform;
```